# IE Remembering Passwords

Tags: windows-7, password-management, internet-explorer-11

I want Internet Explorer to remember a password to a site I previously said do not remember.

Can I access where that is stored and delete it so the next time I enter my password on that site I am again asked whether to remember the password?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not provided information as to what browser you are using...

If you are using IE, follow the instructions outlined here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/fill-in-forms-remember-passwords-autocomplete#ie=ie-11

If you are using FF, follow the instructions outlined here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords

If you are using Chrome, follow the instructions outlined here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?hl=en

If you update your information to provide more detailed information, I can help you come to a more precise answer.

Comment: So I must delete all passwords...I cannot identify a website that I had previously declined remembering the password and change it to remember the password?

Comment: this is a bad answer - does not answer the OPs question

Answer (score 2):

Step (Option) nr 1: Clear all history, cookies as shown, then proceed to step nr 2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>

[image]

Step 2: Make sure when you go to Internet Options > Contents Tab > Auto - Complete Settings that `Usernames and passwords` on forms are ticked as well as the sub - option `Ask me before saving passwords`

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible to access one specific website that Windows was told not to remember the password and change it or must I completely delete all saved passwords and start over?

Comment: The ideal for you would be the Credential Manager feature of Windows: Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\Credential Manager. Unfortunately, I never got it to work before on a website.

Comment: Managing web passwords was added in Windows 8 Credential Manager.  Windows 7 only allows managing network credentials.